# Preselected value not showing in jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a screen with a dropdown which is dynamically populated from a database. I use phonegap and jquery Mobile. The values get added to the dropdown perfectly but one of the values should be pre-selected. The problem is, when the screen shows, there is no selected value in the field (image 1). But when I open the dropdown, the pre-selected value is highlighted (image 2). I use jquery 1.8.3 and jquery mobile 1.2.0.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
selectSubjectsSuccess: function(tx, results){
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var selVal = -1;
        console.log('### szlog: Subjects found: ' + len);
        var subjects = '<option value="">' + sz.langdata['subject'] + '</option>';
        var pre_subject = $('p.plannerfield #subject').data('preselect');
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            subjects += '<option value="' + results.rows.item(i).sj_id + '"';
            if(pre_subject == results.rows.item(i).sj_id){
                subjects += ' selected="selected"';
            }
            subjects += '>' + results.rows.item(i).sj_name + '</option>';
        }
        var sdd = $(".subjectDropdown");
        sdd.empty().append(subjects);
        sdd.selectmenu();
        sdd.selectmenu("refresh", true);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for preselecting the value in dropdown in jquery use

```
<script>
$('#user_tb3 option[value='+ "{{ids}}" +']').attr('selected', 'selected');
</script>
```

write this in body where your select control is ending this will work {{ids}} replace this by the value of your dropdown this will definately work
@bbasmer good luck